# Why jib dockerBuild plugin fails to connect

Tags: docker, maven, jhipster, maven-plugin, jib

I was trying to build the docker image for a project I'm working onto.
It's based on jhipster, after configuring the project it tells me to run the following maven command:

```
./mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, it returns me this errors:

```
[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-pass) has nothing for server URL: registry.hub.docker.com
...
[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-pass) has nothing for server URL: index.docker.io
[WARNING]
```

And finally fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.4.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project booking: (null exception message): NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Recently I worked on a google cloud project, and I edited the `~/.docker/config.json` configuration file. I had to remove google's configuration entries to sort out another problem. Could that be the origin of the problem I'm facing now?

I've tried to do `docker logout` and `docker login` without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Some considerations

I don't know if editing manually the configuration caused the error, in fact I'm pretty sure to have deleted only google-related entries, but nothing referring to docker.* or similar.

To solve this issue, **avoid to edit manually the docker configuration file**. In fact I think that it  should be avoided whenever possible, to avoid configuration problems of any sort.

Instead, just follow what the error message is trying to tell you: *docker is not able to access those urls*. Excluding network problems (which you can troubleshoot with `ping registry-1.docker.io` for example), it should be an authentication problem.

### How to fix

I've found out that running those commands fixed it:

`docker login registry.hub.docker.com`

`docker login registry-1.docker.io`

I don't know if `registry-1.docker.io` is just a mirror of the other first server, which the plugin tries to access after the first unsuccessful connection. You can try to loging to `registry.hub.docker.com` and re-launch the command to see if it sufficient. In case it's not, login to the second one and then it will work.

Comment: Looks like Jib is not able to recognize Access Token created from Docker Hub registry. When we login docker in local its updating ~./docker/config.json file. After that we can able to push.

Answer (score 1):

I ran jib via Gradle:

`./gradlew jibDockerBuild`

and got a similar error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jibDockerBuild'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build to Docker daemon failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/library/openjdk' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help
```

What ended up solving this error for me, bizarrely enough, was to *log out* of Docker Desktop.

I later also tried [funder7's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64620609/2792280) while logged in to Docker Desktop, and that also worked.